# IPython.html.widgets in IPython say: no module named widgets

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

God day for all. I'm trying to execute code from book "IPython Interactive Computing an Visualizing Cookbook" of Cirille Rossant on a Jupyter + IPython environment.

All work fine until I try:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from IPython.display import (display, clear_output, YouTubeVideo)
from IPython.html.widgets import DropdownWidget
```

If I do restart to the kernel appear this message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/html.py:14: ShimWarning: The `IPython.html` package has been deprecated. You should import from `notebook` instead. `IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.
  "`IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.", ShimWarning)
```

then I try to change the third line (the problem) by:

```
from ipywidgets import DropdownWidgets
```

but Jupyter answer: `ImportError: cannot import name 'DropdownWidget'`

*Can somebody help me about?*

***The next is a partial answer***

Well, seeking on the web I find in this page [ipywidgets installation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html) the answer to my question and problem.

I try the next expample and work fine:

```
import numpy as np
url = "http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/f170fecc-18db-44bc-b4fe-5b0b6d2c7297/resource/ec12447d-6b2a-45d0-b0e7-fd69c382e368/download/2013.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
from ipywidgets import interact
@interact
def plot(n=(1, 30)):
    pd.rolling_mean(df['Berri1'], n).dropna().plot()
    plt.ylim(0, 8000)
    plt.show()
```

but jupyter claim that I have to do: `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension`

I go to the terminal obeying the suggestion and jupyter respond:

```
Configure an nbextension to be automatically loaded

Options
-------

Arguments that take values are actually convenience aliases to full
Configurables, whose aliases are listed on the help line. For more information
on full configurables, see '--help-all'.

--debug
    set log level to logging.DEBUG (maximize logging output)
-y
    Answer yes to any questions instead of prompting.
--generate-config
    generate default config file
--section=<Unicode> (EnableNBExtensionApp.section)
    Default: 'notebook'
    Which config section to add the extension to. 'common' will affect all
    pages.

To see all available configurables, use `--help-all`

[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--py'
```

Look that in [1](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html) have the suggestion: `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` but in the console suggest `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension`. Note that there is a little difference but in both cases appear the same error about `--py` option

In this moment the question is partially answered.

Comment: The last error message looks like you need to upgrade `notebook` first. Most widget classes dropped the 'Widget' from their name, so `DropdownWidget` probably became `Dropdown`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, you have reason, looking at the web page in the answer that I have posted, all the syntaxes changed like you say. Now I'm reviewing the notebooks and looking for similar changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeking on web I find on jupyter web page ([jupyter](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython-books/cookbook-code/blob/master/notebooks/chapter01_basic/02_pandas.ipynb)) the revisited notebooks of the book and extraneously almost run fine (*with some exceptions, at least on chapter 01, I go to try with the other chapters*).